# Can someone here has a sample of high pass filter for PCM audio data?

Tags: c++, c, filter, signal-processing, pcm

Good day.
I am poor of DSP. I have difficulties understanding the algorithm.
I have a c# application, a recorder function that will record a sound waves
but this sound is a mixture of all sounds. specifically, when i receive
the data i will filter this data to save only the filtered audio data with high frequency, 
example cutoff frequency is 15khz.
For this filter, given are
 the samples of data with size,
and the cutoff frequency

C/C++ is fine

At the time i received that samples of data, apply highpass filter then save the result to the wav.

-thong

Answer (score 8):

You need to know the sample rate and also have a reasonable idea of your filter specification before you can design a suitable filter. Just specifying a 15 kHz cut-off is not really enough, e.g. you might want something like this:

```
Sample rate: 44.1 kHz
Stop-band: < 12 kHz
Stop-band rejection: > 80 dB
Pass-band: > 15 kHz
Passband ripple: +/- 1 dB
```

You can then feed these parameters into a filter design package and this will give you all the filter coefficients etc.

Note that the complexity of the filter (i.e. filter order = number of stages or "taps") will be highly dependent on the filter specification, so ideally you want to use  a filter design package which lets you play around with the spec easily so that you can trade off your design requirements against the required compute bandwidth.

You will also need to decide whether phase and/or group delay are important to you - use a linear phase FIR for a constant group delay (more expensive) or a recursive IIR if phase/delay are not critical (much cheaper to implement).

Note that there are free online filter design packages available, e.g. http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/ looks pretty good (it can even generate a C code filter implementation for you), although it may require at least beginner-level signal-processing knowledge when it comes to selecting filter types etc.

---

To help understand basic filter design parameters, here is a useful diagram from http://dspguru.com. Note that this is for a low pass filter, but the same parameters apply in the high pass case.

[image]

Comment: thank you for that very informative one.

The samples that i received was a 44.1kHz
I don't know about the pass band and stop band.
I am not sure if stop band and pass band is for bandpass filter..

in c++, I recieved the data in waveInProc callback...
basically this audio data is a mixture of sounds of different frequencies.
I will apply a high pass filter to this audio data with 15kHz(example) cutoff. so that frequency above 15khz will only be save on the wav file.

Comment: @tongy: the important thing you need to understand is that there is no such thing as a perfect or *ideal* filter - this is why we define a *stop band* and a *pass band* and between these there is a *transition band* (i.e. between 12 and 15 kHz in the above example). You need a good understanding of what you are trying to achieve before you can create a suitable filter specification.

Comment: Mr. Paul,

thank you. i see...

According to my understanding that high pass filter  do not need of passband ripple or stop band, i think.

Comment: @tongy: that is not correct - *every* physically realisable filter has a pass band and a stop band (otherwise it wouldn't be a filter !). There will *always* be variation in gain (aka ripple) in the pass band. There is also variation in gain in the stop band, but usually we just specify a maximum gain for the stop band (or minimum stop band rejection). You need to understand these fundamental parameters before you can even begin to attempt to design a filter.

Comment: @tongy : Only a perfect and infinitely long high-pass filter will have no passband.  So if you are willing to wait until you are dead and the Universe ends for your filter to finish running...  Otherwise, pick a passband.

Comment: Mr. paul, thank you very much...i am now looking into that link that you have given..

@hotpaw2, thank you for that information...