# How to amplify certain audio samples, particularly amplifying a certain frequency?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Can anyone provide sample pseudocode or share some existing link that has sample code.

Like for example I have a mix audio of 1kHz or 2kHz or 8kHz or so, and I want to boost certain frequencies like 1kHz only in real-time.

Reading some DSP books and resources confuses me.

Comment: Duplicate (same user): [Can someone here has a sample of high pass filter for PCM audio data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062671/can-someone-here-has-a-sample-of-high-pass-filter-for-pcm-audio-data)

Comment: Also see http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone here has a sample of high pass filter for PCM audio data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062671/can-someone-here-has-a-sample-of-high-pass-filter-for-pcm-audio-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to design and implement a suitable [digital filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter). This is a large and complex subject area though, so you won't get a simple answer here. Probably the best thing as a first step would be to read a good introductory book on DSP, e.g. [Understanding DSP by Rick Lyons](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Digital-Signal-Processing-Richard/dp/0137027419), which is a very good for beginners as it's not too heavy on the math and has a more practical bent than most such introductory DSP books.

For this particular application though what you are trying to do is similar to implementing a [graphic equalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_equalizer#Graphic_equalizer), and there are many pointers to how to implement this kind of thing if you use e.g. "graphic equalizer" as a search term.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of math behind digital filtering. Sorry, I think it is important to at least understand basic filters (like those used in electronics). If you don't want to go through the basics: best to get an audio graphics equaliser where you can play with the (virtual) sliders. If you want to implement a very specific filter, please read on.

Real time: depends on your computing platform. If this is a small micro (like AVR, Microchip PIC,..) you'll need an efficient algorithm. This is likely a IIR band pass filter. The equivalent of a graphics equaliser consists of multiple band pass filters, all summed together. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response

A more computing intensive algorithm uses FIR filters. In that case you can also control the phase of the filtered signal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response

If you find an algorithm (i.e. IIR), you'll need to calculate the coefficients. The algorithm is simple, calculating the coefficients is not.

I found a book matching your question: [Audio digital signal processing in real time](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.198.3684&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=r3rgTsmUIMPLsga9gu3jCA&usg=AFQjCNHs3eoJ9XppES3JiwtjjmcrjE2TCQ&sig2=0nVHZ6dSTTLTXjL7rGQMbA)
I browsed through it; it seems to have the right answers.

Comment: Thanks for that, Yeah, i understand basic filters already after reading some resources. It is not quite easy. as it needs more understanding the mathematical procedures, but theory wise is understandable... implementation is not that quite easy, without copying some open source examples..